# How to create a checkbox in a button? (javafx)

Tags: javafx

How to create a checkbox in a button? If it is possible to create it through the fxml file it would be better for me, but also another option would be good.

I tried to put the CheckBox tag inside the Button tag. But it didn't work

```
<Button text="Write All" styleClass="smallSideButton" style="-fx-pref-width: 120px;" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="7">
     <CheckBox/>
</Button>
```

Comment: A `Button` is a `Labeled` which has a `graphic` property which can be set to any arbitrary `Node`.

Comment: show us your `fxml` file,maybe there is a mistake

Comment: I edited the question I added the part of the fxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
         <graphic>
            <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
         </graphic>
      </Button>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Great, it works! Why do I need the "mnemonicParsing" property?

Comment: @Shlomi You may not, though it is `true` by default for `Button`s and `CheckBox`es. All that property means is that, when `true`, if the `text` is set to something like `"_Save"` then the `_` is interpreted as a [mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_(keyboard)) with `S` as the target. That said, it's likely Przemek didn't intentionally add the `mnemonicParsing` attribute but it was actually added by _Scene Builder_ which appears to disable mnemonic parsing for everything by default; since the property would otherwise be `true`, _Scene Builder_ has to manually set it to `false`.